# knitr: put output on top of the page

Tags: r, knitr

I am generating a HTML file with knitr. I am using a for-loop for several plots which are written in the HTML file inside this loop. In this for-loop further data is created.
Is there a possibility to put this data above the plots I create?

I have written a minimal example to explain my question better: is there a way to put the output of `a` on top of the page, above the output created in the for-loop?

````
```{r}
a <- 10
for (x in 1:10) {
 a <- a*x
 cat(x, "\n")
}
cat(a)

```
````

Comment: So you just want the final value of `a` (=36288000) above the beginning of the for loop?

Comment: You could just use the chunk option `echo` to specify which lines of output you want. Or, if you want to also show the code, combine the above with a 2nd chunk and not execute the 2nd one via chunk option `eval= FALSE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to use two separate code chunks to achieve your desired results.  The first chunk would perform all of the calculations and chart generation and store the information in variables.  Then in the second chunk simply outputs the contents of the variables (to include data and plots) in the desired order.

Using your example above, you would have:

````
```{r}
a <- 10
result <- numeric(10)
for (x in 1:10) {
 a <- a*x
 result[x] <- x
}
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
cat(a)
for (x in 1:10) {
     cat(result[x], "\n")
}
```
````

The first chunk does all of the computing but displays nothing.  The second chunk then outputs the information in whatever order you want.  The important thing to note here is that whatever gets calculated and stored in earlier chunks is available for use in later chunks so you can extend this across multiple sections of your document.

Comment: Basically what I said above. But you need the `echo= FALSE` option in chunk 1 so that you get what the author asked for-- the results above the code. Your solution doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks you, that seems to be a lot easier than I thought. I will adapt that later in my document.

Comment: @Alex actually there is a fundamental difference between our answers. Yours requires duplication of the code which introduces opportunities for errors and becomes a maintenance issue.  Second, the OP indicated she wanted the code output before the plots but was silent about echoing the code itself.  Therefore I left the choice of `echo = FALSE` to the user.

Comment: @DaddytheRunner agreed on the fundamental difference. And you have good points on duplication. But the OP states 'is there a way to put the output of a' (which is a numeric, not a plot) above the loop. That's what my point was about and, I believe, would require duplication.